# How to Save a Selection List Choice in jStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jstorage

I have an app I'm developing (still) and asked a question recently about how to Save a Selection List Choice in JavaScript. I have since then been introduced to jStorage, an extension of jQuery which I have been using for my code. I was wondering if I could save the selected value in jStorage much easier instead? The HTML code for my selection list is as follows;

```
<select name = 'job' id = 'job' style = 'width: auto; background-color: #777; color: white; font-size: 20px; border-color: #AAA;'>
 <option value = 'jobselect'>Select Profession</option>
 <option value = 'job1'>Mechanical Engineer</option>
 <option value = 'job2'>Software Engineer</option>
 <option value = 'jobother'>Other</option>
</select>
```

and I had this in my JavaScript file to save the selected value;

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ListChoice() {

    var input1 = document.getElementById('job');

    if (localStorage['job']) {  
        input1.value = localStorage['job'];
    }

    input1.onchange = function() {  
        localStorage['job'] = this.value;
    }

});
```

I have two other functions in my JS file called **loadSettings** and **saveSettings**, is there a way to change the code above to save the selected value of the list to jStorage in my functions?? Just wondering if it would be easier to save to jStorage. Thanks a lot in advance xx

Comment: *jStorage* doesn't have a builtin function to retrieve/set the value of form fields, so you would still have to write your own *loadSettings* and *saveSettings*.

Answer (score 0):

NB: Something like http://garlicjs.org/ may be a shortcut to your problems.

Not sure if this can help you out but you can set the jstorage with something like the following (I'd just serialize the entire form):

```
$.jStorage.set('jobValues', $('#job').serializeArray());
```

And then you need to iterate through the array in a manner such as:

```
        var currentStorage = $.jStorage.get('jobValues');
        if (currentStorage) {
            $.each(currentStorage, function(position,object){
                $("input[name='"+object['name']+"']").prop('value', object['value']);               
            });
        }
```